# T-SQL query on huge table running slow depending on join conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

we have a huge table of companies (17 million entries) for which we want to find duplicates according to search critera (based on phone number). The query runs very slow (5 minutes+)

Here is a simplified version of the query, but the problem is the same :

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM dbo.Company AS C1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.Company AS C2 ON C2.sTelephone = C1.sTelephone 
                         AND C1.iId_company != C2.iId_company 
                         AND (C1.iId_third_party_id IS NULL OR 
                              C2.iId_third_party_id IS NULL)
```

Columns explanation :

- iId_company : Primary key, integer auto increment
- sTelephone : Phone number of the company, varchar with non-clustered index on it
- iId_third_party_id : ID from a third party provider, may be null when users insert themself new companies (for that we want to find duplicates), integer with a non-clustered index on it too.

What we what is the companies with the same phone number, but different primary keys (duplicates), and also that one part doesn't have a third party ID (which tells us that a end user inserted it.

Now, I tried some things but gave me no clue :

- When removing one side in the **OR** clause, only remaining **C1.iId_third_party_id IS NULL** gives a HUGE boost, the query takes like less than 5 seconds
- When removing completely the condition in parenthesis with the **OR** clause, the query then comes slow again (1 minute +), but I think it's only because the data set to return in very huge.

I ended up making UNION to combine both queries (each with its part on the **OR** condition) but I would like to understand why there is so much difference when using that **OR** in the condition.

Comment: I try to make this in a single query, but it seems very haed to keep good performance, and have it in a single query. My solution using an UNION seems to be pretty good since all answers until now are using multiple queries to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to figure out why there are such differences in performance is to examine the execution plan for the queries you tried. They can provide a lot of information. Unfortunately, I am not an SQL Server expert, so I can't tell how the execution plans can be obtained.

Comment: I already looked at the execution plan, but it does not give me clues. I am not very used to analyze the execution plans.

Comment: That is unfortunate. Because when working with large amount of data, the execution plan can give a lot of hints in terms of optimization of the queries (additional indexes to be added, query hints, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea if this will be any help in terms of performance (since I don't have a 17mio. row table at hand to test), but how about this:

- select the minimum amount of information you absolutely need (don't do SELECT C1.* !!)
- group by telephone number and count occurences
- any "telephone number group" with 2 or more occurences needs to be inspected more closely

Since you're on SQL Server 2008, you should be able to create something like this (a Common Table Expression - CTE). This should reduce the scope of search, since only (hopefully!) few entries in the Company table will be indeed duplicated - so this should limit your search and thus speed it up (or at least that's the hope!).

```
WITH PhoneDuplicates AS
(SELECT c.Telephone, COUNT(*) as PhoneCount
   FROM dbo.Company AS c 
   GROUP BY c.Telephone
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT 
  (list of fields from company table)
FROM
  dbo.Company AS c
INNER JOIN
  PhoneDuplicates as PD ON PD.Telephone = c.Telephone
```

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, what is the cardinality of your filtering columns?

Maybe having only

```
C1.iId_third_party_id IS NULL
```

gave a boost to performance because SQL could tell (from the statistics built on the index) that relatively few rows met the necessary criteria. When you added

```
(... OR C2.iId_third_party_id IS NULL)
```

perhaps SQL figured the resulting join would produce so many matching rows that it would not be efficient to use the index on that column.

Similarly, how many matching/duplicate phone numbers will there be? **If** this situation is very infrequent, I'd do something like marc_s's query (he beat me to it), as that would fly.

A lot depends on what the data looks like--how frequently or infrequently your filtering criteria appear. Analyze that, try and understand how it is and how it might change over time, and design your queries accordingly.

Comment: When the query actually ends, it returns between 10000 and 20000 rows

Answer (score 1):

the speed increase you see when removing the OR part is because an OR automaticaly does an index scan instead of a seek. by unioning them together you do 2 seeks which is faster.

try finding the dupes using the the row_number technique:

```
;with cteDupes(RN, DupeID, DupeTelephone) as
(
SELECT  row_number() over(partition by sTelephone order by iId_company, sTelephone) RN,
        iId_company, sTelephone
FROM    dbo.Company 
WHERE   iId_third_party_id IS NULL
)
select * from cteDupes
where RN > 1
```

this will return only duped rows.
the bonus of this is that you only get one table pass instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is

```
SELECT C1.*
FROM (select * from dbo.Company where iId_third_party_id IS NULL) AS C1 WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN (select * from dbo.Company where iId_third_party_id IS NULL) AS C2 ON C2.sTelephone = C1.sTelephone 
                         AND C1.iId_company != C2.iId_company
```

As this has helped us before.

Comment: I don't think this would work because your sub-queries create a "AND", making only results that both have NULL to be returned when only one of them needs to be NULL for the join to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt both your non-clustered indexes are going to be used (`sTelephone`, `iId_third_party_id`).  Are you clustering on the primary key?

Look at the estimated execution plan.

Off the top of my head without seeing the plan, I would think about adding the `iId_third_party_id` to the nonclustered index on `sTelephone` and if you aren't clustering on the primary key, then add the `iId_company` to the index as well.

Note that there is also a potential for cross-join multiplication of results when there are more than two duplicates for a given phone number.

Answer (score 0):

```
With Temp as
(Select *
FROM dbo.Company as c
Where c.iId_third_party_id is NULL)

Select C1.*
From temp as C1 With (NoLock)
INNER JOIN Temp AS C2 
ON C2.sTelephone = C1.sTelephone AND C1.iId_company != C2.iId_company
```

Something like this might work